# Get total number of records in index for Algolia - Javascript

Tags: javascript, algolia

How can i get the total number of records in an index, with algolia?

I'd like to avoid doign an empty search with a number of items per page set to a million or something.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Every search result from Algolia has an attribute of `nbHits`. To get the total number of records, do an empty query with no filters and grab that number.

If you care about the size of the results, you can also set the `attributesToRetrieve` to `null` which will return only the `objectID` and make the result a bit snappier.

Comment: Thanks! That was it.

Comment: +1 In addition to setting `attributesToRetrieve` to `null`, you can reduce the response size even further by also setting `attributesToHighlight` to `null`.  But if you're _only_ interested in getting the total record count then your best best would be to set `hitsPerPage` to `0` (and potentially setting `analytics` to `false`).